# Get last row that satisfies a condition using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, filtering

I have a DataFrame like this:

| date_from | date_to | item_id | VALUE_NEW | VALUE_OLD | cost_var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/1900 00:00:00 | 11/3/2022 15:31:18 | 452953 | 5366,46 | 4024,71 | 33.34% |
| 11/3/2022 15:31:18 | 1/1/2200 00:00:00 | 452953 | 9122,57 | 5366,46 | 69.99% |
| 1/1/1900 00:00:00 | 11/3/2022 15:31:18 | 452954 | 5366,46 | 4024,71 | 33.34% |
| 11/3/2022 15:31:18 | 1/1/2200 00:00:00 | 452954 | 9122,57 | 5366,46 | 69.99% |
| 1/1/1900 00:00:00 | 21/7/2021 16:30:46 | 452961 | 6170,98 | 4024,71 | 53.33% |
| 21/7/2021 16:30:46 | 11/3/2022 15:31:09 | 452961 | 5312 | 6170,98 | 13.92% |
| 11/3/2022 15:31:09 | 1/1/2200 00:00:00 | 452961 | 9122,57 | 5312 | 71.74% |
| 1/1/1900 00:00:00 | 13/10/2021 14:39:55 | 801286 | 4052,1 | 1332,8 | 204.03% |
| 13/10/2021 14:39:55 | 13/10/2021 14:43:09 | 801286 | 4,4732 | 4052,1 | 99.89% |
| 13/10/2021 14:43:09 | 3/2/2022 17:16:23 | 801286 | 4473,2 | 4,4732 | 99900.00% |
| 3/2/2022 17:16:23 | 1/1/2200 00:00:00 | 801286 | 4946,8 | 4473,2 | 10.59% |

I need to check each item_id, and get the last row where cost_var is >60%. If it's the last row, that's ok, but if there is a next one, and it is <60%, I have to drop the last row>60%. Output should look like this:

| date_from | date_to | item_id | VALUE_NEW | VALUE_OLD | cost_var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/3/2022 15:31:18 | 1/1/2200 00:00:00 | 452953 | 9122,57 | 5366,46 | 69.99% |
| 11/3/2022 15:31:18 | 1/1/2200 00:00:00 | 452954 | 9122,57 | 5366,46 | 69.99% |
| 11/3/2022 15:31:09 | 1/1/2200 00:00:00 | 452961 | 9122,57 | 5312 | 71.74% |

Item 802186 returned no value, because last row>60% (99900.00%) has a next row and cost_var<60% (10.59%)... Is it possible to do? I couldn't find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can select the last row of each `item_id` using `groupby` and only select ones where `cost_var > 60%` using `query`.

```py
df.groupby('item_id', as_index=False).last().query("cost_var.str.rstrip('%').astype('float')>60")
```

[image]